# Alternate for display:none

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there any alternate for

```
display:none;
```

I am using jquery to show a div only on click. This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#showmenu').click(function() {
    $('#showmenu').text($('.sidebarmenu').is(':visible') ? 'Show Menu' : 'Hide Menu');
    $('.sidebarmenu').toggle("slide");
 });
});
```

This is my HTML

```
<button id="showmenu" type="button">Show menu</button></div>
<div class="sidebarmenu" style="display: none;">
   Can the button value change to "show" or "hide"
</div>
```

But I can't use

```
 display:none;
```

What are the other ways to achieve [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KEsBR/2/)

Comment: You need to provide more context/code for this to make sense.

Comment: Use opacity? Just remember to prefix it for older browsers.

Comment: what is the exact error , can you please explain ?

Comment: you could absolutely position it off the viewport if you don't want it to take up any space

Comment: XY question? Provide more informations about the problem

Comment: There are lots of alternatives. There is no way to tell if any of them are suitable without knowing why using `display: none` is causing the other code to break. The best solution is almost certainly going to be to stop the other code from breaking when display: none is used instead of not using display: none.

Comment: or you can use `text-indent: -99999px;` so many ways for so many problems

Comment: You can use any sample provided in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/Bxqxt/) based on your needs. And this is not exhaustive either.

Comment: Please find my edited post.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide it and force it to not take up any space with these lines:

```
visibility: hidden;
height: 0;
width: 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers: you could also:

1. move the element outside of the user's viewport, like:

   ```
   position: fixed;
   left: -99999; /* or without the minus, depends */
   top: -99999; /* or without the minus, depends */
   ```
2. Use opacity:

   ```
   opacity: 0;
   ```
3. A dirty way to make text "invisible" for the user, but readable for machines is to create an element with white background and white text. ;) Please note that google has powerful algorithms to detect this and sees this as SEO fraud when overused. Don't overuse it (see SEO blogs for more info) or your site will be ranked down.

Answer (score 1):

Also check [**HTML5 “the hidden attribute”**](http://jaspreetchahal.org/html5-attribute-hidden-equivalent-to-css-displaynone/)

```
<div hidden>This is hidden</div>
```

Comment: are we moving back to font="" center etc? Why they've added this attribute? omg

Comment: While I encourage wider awareness of the `hidden` attribute, note that (a) it is NOT the same as `display:none`. The `hidden` attribute carries semantics about the relevance of its element's contents in a way that `display:none` does not; (b) the presentational aspect of the hidden attribute is achieved by applying `display:none` to the element on which it appears, so any problem that is caused by `display:none` will also be caused by adding the `hidden` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In case it contains only text, just set its font size to 0:

```
<div id="Div1">You won't see me</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Div1 { font-size: 0px; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkKnR/).

Answer (score 0):

you can also try with `visibility` attribute.

```
 visibility:hidden
```

Comment: Please note that THIS will not show the element, but occupy the space that would be needed on the page. You'll have an empty area in your page then.

Comment: set height and width attribute to 0.